# Pausing and resuming a self contained scrapy script

Tags: python, web, web-scraping, scrapy, web-crawler

I'm running a self contained Scrapy spider, which lives in a single `.py` file. In case of server fail/power outage/any other reason that the script might fail, is there an elegant way to make sure that I will be able to resume a run after recovery?

Maybe something similar to the built in JOBDIR setting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can still use JOBDIR option if you have a self-contained script, e.g. you can set a value in [custom_settings](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spiders.html#scrapy.spiders.Spider.custom_settings) attribute:

```
class MySpider(scrapy.Spider):
    custom_settings = {
        'JOBDIR': './job',
    }
    #...
```

Alternatively, you can set this option when creating [CrawlerProcess](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/api.html#scrapy.crawler.CrawlerProcess) (if that's what you're using to run spiders in a script):

```
process = CrawlerProcess({'JOBDIR': './job'})
process.crawl(MySpider)
process.start()
```

Comment: Looks like i'll have to stick to scrapy's mechanism, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

There's a whole [documentation page](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/jobs.html#jobs-pausing-and-resuming-crawls) covering this issue:

> To start a spider with persistence supported enabled, run it like
>   this:
>
> `scrapy crawl somespider -s JOBDIR=crawls/somespider-1`
>
> Then, you can stop the spider safely at any time (by pressing Ctrl-C
>   or sending a signal), and resume it later by issuing the same command:
>
> `scrapy crawl somespider -s JOBDIR=crawls/somespider-1`

Comment: What i have is a self contained spider module, not a whole project generated by the "startproject" key word, this unfortunately doesn't apply to my situation. Also, i'm looking for a way to continuously save the state of the spider in order to make sure that i have a way of recovery in a case of server failure, not in a case of a gentle pause.

Comment: @m.livs oh sorry I missed that part. Why not just have a scrapy project? Having whatever project you have in one single module is never a good idea unless it's under 50 lines of code or so.

Comment: I'm trying to use only the parts that i need from Scrapy . even if i did use a full project, the -S mechanism doesn't help in a case of a violent stop...

Comment: @m.livs if JOBDIR doesn't work in case of violent stop it could be helpful to raise an issue in scrapy bug tracker (https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/issues/), or maybe comment on existing issue (https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/issues/845?)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [supervisor](http://supervisord.org/running.html#adding-a-program/).

```
[program:foo]
command=~/script_path/script.py
```

Comment: I'll look into that, Thanks!